# htaccess to redirect/remove /?filter_tag[0]=

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

`Joomla` has an issue that was adding `/?filter_tag[0]=` to the urls.  I now see them in `Google Search Console`.

What is the `htaccess` code to redirect/remove `/?filter_tag[0]=`

Example URL:
`https://www.example.com/storefront-scissor-gate-mounting-options/?filter_tag[0]=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule as your **top rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_tag\[0\]= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,NE,R=301]
```

`?` after `%{REQUEST_URI}` will remove query string from URI.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I love learning new stuff like this.  I can now use this for other query string issues.